# 32-bit web app on 64-bit server 2003 is not running

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

We have a web application built with target framework as x86.

On Server 2008 (IIS 7/7.5) we are able to run the application without any issue (For 64 bit system we enable 32 bit application from app pool).

On 32 bit server 2003 - no issue.

On 64 bit server 2003 (SP2) - we are unable to load a dll:

> Could not load file or assembly 'acPDFCreatorLib.Net' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

We know this error comes on 64 bit system when Enable 32bit application is set to false. So I tried the following:

Ran the script:

```
 cscript %SYSTEMDRIVE%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32bitAppOnWin64 1
```

The issue persisted.

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

On running this the World Wide Web Publishing service stops.

On trying to restart we are getting the following error

> ISAPI Filter 'C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a AMD64 processor architecture.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed the issue for me:-

1. Right Click "Web Sites" and select property
2. Go to Services tab.
3. Uncheck - "Run WWW services in IIS 5.0 isolation mode".

After removing the selection from Run WWW Services...., I was able to start the service.

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me regarding the issue "**Could not load file or assembly 'acPDFCreatorLib.Net' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format**."

1. Go to **Application Pools** => Select the **AppPool** you have created (Else Choose DefaultAppPool or ASP .Net v4.0)
2. Right click AppPool and Select **Advanced Settings**
3. Set **Enable 32-bit Applications** to **True**
4. **Reset IIS** and Check